# Setting a ToolStripLabel in a thread-safe manner

Tags: c#, thread-safety, multithreading, toolstrip

I have a `ToolStripLabel` that needs to have its `Text` property updated from an event handler on a separate thread.  Normally with a regular `Label` I've been using the `InvokeRequired` property and invoking a delegate to do the work if `InvokeRequired` returns true.  The trouble is that `ToolStripLabel` doesn't have this property.  What is the cleanest way to get this text updated in a thread-safe manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `InvokeRequired` on the ToolStrip control instead of the ToolStripLabel.